# Searching database using multiple textboxes using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have 6 textboxes and one search button...
My search button should search row from database if one textbox is filled or two,three textboxes are filled, Altogether search should work even if one textbox is filled or all the 6 textboxes are filled

Comment: Sounds neat, what's your question?

Comment: Thanks every one for the reply,

Answer (score 0):

I'll speculate a bit on the intent of your question. Do you want to:

1. Search a SQL Server table based on manual input of one or more search terms?
2. Avoid using ad-hoc SQL to prevent injection attacks?

If so, I'd recommend a SQL-Server table-valued function that converts a delimited string into a table variable which can be used just like any other table in your query.

Here is an example function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnVarcharListToTable](@List varchar(8000), @Delim char(1) = NULL)
RETURNS @TableVar TABLE(ID int identity(1,1), Val varchar(256) collate database_default)
AS
BEGIN
    --note that each element will be trimmed of whitespace

    declare
        @DelimIndex     int

    If (@Delim IS NULL) SET @Delim = ','

    select @List = ltrim(rtrim(@List))

    if (left(@List,1) = @Delim)
        begin
            select @List = ltrim(right(@List,len(@List) - 1))
        end

    if (right(@List,1) = @Delim)
        begin
            select @List = rtrim(left(@List,len(@List) - 1))
        end

    while (CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List, 1) > 0)
    begin
        select @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List, 1)
        insert into @TableVar (Val) select left(ltrim(rtrim(left(@List,@DelimIndex-1))), 256)
        select @List = ltrim(right(@List,len(@List) - @DelimIndex))
    end

    if (@List) <> ''
        --get the last item
        begin
            insert into @TableVar (Val) select ltrim(rtrim(@List))
        end

   RETURN
END
```

As for the client side, imagine you have a form with 6 text boxes and you want to pass in values from the text boxes containing text. You can do that using the mechanism below:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim searchterms = String.Join("|", From textbox In {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5, TextBox6} Where textbox.Text <> String.Empty Select textbox.Text)

    If searchterms = String.Empty Then
        MessageBox.Show("No Search Terms Defined")
    End If

    Using cn = New SqlConnection("Server=YourServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=YourDatabase")
        cn.Open()

        Using cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customer INNER JOIN dbo.fnVarcharListToTable(@searchterms,'|') SearchTerms on SearchTerms.val = Customer.Name", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchterms", searchterms)

            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read
                    MessageBox.Show("Found: " + reader("Name").ToString())
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```